# Quadratic LineElement. How does it differ from linear LineElement?

Tags: finite-element-method, undocumented

This is a general question about quadratic LineElement.
It does not appear to be documented or have examples of its use.

What is it ?
Does it have 1 or 2 dimensions ?
Are there any examples of its use ?

I am going to be generating lattices of 100-5000 LineElements and would like to understand if there are any benefits to using quadratic over linear LineElements.

Comment: The quadratic elements allow for order-2 interpolation in solving PDEs and so generally lead to more accurate solutions.  The quadratic points need not be collinear with the vertices in a `TriangleElement`; if the `LineElements` are in 1D (${\bf R^1}$), then they would be collinear obviously.

Answer (score 2):

The `LineElement` is documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/LineElement.html). Since the default mesh order is 2 all default 1D meshes use a second order line element. This is a 1D element with 3 degrees of freedom (all along the x-axis). Second order elements typically give better quality results, also because the use higher order integration points than first order elements. The 'drawback` is, that they take slightly longer to compute.

Comment: Here `netz=ToElementMesh[{{0}, {3}, {4}, {7}}]` a 1D mesh is created which has `netz["MeshOrder"]=1`. Does this not contradict your statement "default mesh order is 2"?  I tried to create a quadratic mesh `ToElementMesh[{{0}, {3}, {4}, {7}},"MeshOrder"->2]]` but MeshOrder doesn't change. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, the correct (documented) syntax for this is ToElementMesh["Coordinates"->{{0}, {3}, {4}, {7}}]; as you do not give a connectivity a Delaunay triangulation is computed from the points. By definition this can only be first order; if you want to convert that to a second order mesh you'd have to use MeshOrderAlteration. I probably could make the option MeshOrder->2 work for that case, but then the question would be why one needs to specify that when in all other cases it's the default. So that answer to your question is that a Delauney triangulation is first order by definition.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer!